# ReactiveX - Single<T> to Single<R>

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, reactivex, clean-architecture, rx-kotlin

I'm looking to make a sample project with a clean architecture approach and i have some difficulties to transform a single to another.

I have my retrofit service (with a Single) :

```
@GET("nearbysearch/json") fun getNearbyPlaces(@Query("type") type: String, @Query("location") location: String, @Query("radius") radius: Int): Single<GooglePlacesNearbySearchResult>
```

And i use it in my repository implementation :

```
override fun getNearbyPlaces(type: String, location: String, radius: Int): Single<List<Place>> {
    return googlePlacesApi.getNearbyPlaces(type, location, radius)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnSuccess { googlePlacesNearbySearchResult -> nearbyPlaceListResultMapper.transform(googlePlacesNearbySearchResult) }
}
```

In this single, i want to transform my `Single<GooglePlacesNearbyResultSearch>` to a `Single<List<Place>>`, and i want to do this with my mapper `NearbyPlaceListResultMapper`

The issue is i don't succeed in having a `Single<List<Place>>` at the end. I can transform it to an Observable or a Completable but not the Single one.

Can anyone help me to have it in a cleaner way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `nearbyPlaceListResultMapper.transform` returns the type `List<Place>>` you can use the `map` operation.

```
fun getNearbyPlaces(type: String, location: String, radius: Int): Single<List<Place>> {
    return googlePlacesApi.getNearbyPlaces(type, location, radius)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { nearbyPlaceListResultMapper.transform(it) }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
}
```